# For positive integers $a,b,c,\,a<c,\,b<c$, then $ab<d$. Can $d$ be written in solely in terms of $c$ more restricted than $d=c^2$?

Tags: inequality

Given some positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$, and the inequalities $a<c$, $b<c$ and $ab<d$, is there a way to rewrite $d$ purely as a function of $c$? Like $ab<f(c)$, what would $f(c)$ be? And I am referring to an exact bound. We can obviously say $ab<c^2$, but can that be made smaller or is that the most restricted?

Comment: Without any further restrictions, you can't say that $ab<c^2$.  For example, let $a = -1$, $b = -2$, $c = 0$.  Then, $a,b<c$, but $ab>c^2$.

Comment: @Doug and if they are positive integers?

Comment: If they are positive, then $ab<c^2$ is true.

Comment: @Doug is there a smaller restriction than c^2 or is that the lowest one can guarantee?

Comment: I don't think you can say anything about how $c$ and $d$ are related without more information.  For example, there is nothing so far that prevents either $d<c$ or $d>c$ from being true.

Comment: If all are positive we can't say anything more restrictive then $ab < c^2$.  For any $\delta < c^2$ we can find $a,b < c$ where $ab > \delta$ (can you see why?)

Comment: @fleablood:  with the specification that they are positive integers you can do better.

Comment: Oh.. I missed that they were restricted to integers.

Comment: Hint:  in the integers, $a \lt c$ can also be written $a \le c-1$  Where does that take you?

Comment: If they are integers than $a < c \iff a \le c-1$ and $b<c \iff b \le c-1 $ and $ab \le d $.  Thus we have $ab \le (c-1)^2$ and so if $d> ab$ then $d > (c-1)^2$.

Comment: The title of this question (to which the answer is obviously: no) does not coerrespond to what is actually asked for.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Title has been modified to reflect.

Comment: @XavierBorisov The rewriting of the title made it even worse. Hint: the word "written" is totally out of place, and the equality $d=c^2$ that is supposedly not restricted enough is just not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a<c\ \text{ and }\ b<c\ \implies a\leq c-1\ \text{ and }\ b\leq c-1$$
$$\ \implies\ ab \leq (c-1)^2 \implies ab < (c-1)^2 +1.$$

So the minimum $d$ can be is $(c-1)^2 + 1.$